# Typescript returns "and" instead of "or" for parameters of functions

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm currently developing a React Native app with Typescript.

I have a massive data download from server and a function for saving all data in it's corresponding table.

```
static insertVariousTable = (table: TypeTables) => {
    switch (table) {
      case 'clase':
        return Clase.insertVarious;
      case 'estadoequipo':
        return EstadoEquipo.insertVarious;
      case 'formapesopatron':
        return FormaPesoPatron.insertVarious;
    }
  };
```

When I call the function the type is: (note that the return types could be any of them, I mean "or" (|) instead of "and" (&) and that's ok for me)

```
let insertVarious: ((rows: ClaseType[]) => Promise<unknown>) | ((rows: TypeEstadoEquipo[]) => Promise<unknown>) | ((rows: FormaPesoPatronType[]) => Promise<...>) | undefined
```

But when I'm trying to call the function with await (inside an async function) it changes the types of the function parameters to "and" (&).

```
async function download(res:IRes){
for (key in res.data) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(res.data, key)) {
      const tabla = res.data[key];
      let insertVarious = DbRequests.insertVariousTable(key);
      if (insertVarious) {
        await insertVarious(tabla);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The "await insertVarios(tabla)" parameter type becomes: (with "and" (&))

```
let insertVarious: (rows: ClaseType[] & TypeEstadoEquipo[] & FormaPesoPatronType[]) => Promise<unknown>
```

I need the type to be "or" (|) so I can send any of them, how can I fix this?

Please help....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide reproducible example, for instance in TS playgrounnd. Apart from that, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type#answer-50375286) answer and [my article](https://catchts.com/react-props) with small understandable examples. FUnction union is not want you want for sure

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
let insertVarious: 
   | undefined 
   | <T extends ClaseType | TypeEstadoEquipo | FormaPesoPatronType>((rows: T[]) => Promise<unknown>)
```

Or, if you care about the return type:

```
let insertVarious: 
   | undefined 
   | <T extends ClaseType | TypeEstadoEquipo | FormaPesoPatronType>((rows: T[]) => Promise<T extends FormaPesoPatronType  ? <...> : unknown>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to [this issue posted on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33591), and can be solved by defining an `InsertVariousType` as:

```js
type InsertVariousType = (<T extends Array<ClaseType | TypeEstadoEquipo | FormaPesoPatronType>>(rows: T) => Promise<unknown>) | undefined
```

and use this type to cast the `DbRequests.insertVariousTable` return value as `InsertVariousType`.

```js
async function download(res:IRes){
    for (let key in res.data) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(res.data, key)) {
            const tabla = res.data[key as TypeTables];
            const insertVarious = DbRequests.insertVariousTable(key as TypeTables) as InsertVariousType;
            if (insertVarious) {
                await insertVarious(tabla);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIBs4GcIBUCeADigN4BQylycAXMlmFKAOZkC+ZZCmWWaPpClQZwwwBMlA4oYAGpwmAewCufALzIAFFEUB3LHQCCUKHHwAeDNjxEIAPgCUyNXeTkqH5FAhhlUEMggELrIAAo6ALbAONoQWIroAG4oLl5xCcmajMoQDk7YYZHREObKIADWIHogdkKUHBxkoJCwiCgExACiIgAmip0AjsrAhIpudcgARnQMTCCsjdzYfN1gcH2Dw6PjHiJiElLQcgrAKupaOvpGJmbmHRCr6-1DI4qOzq7unpTevv6BwUKiiiMW88SSKVcYIyECyUByeWofHCwOKpQqVV0NQmDU4zWg8CQyAAYoooBE4KF0qFRDoQPcdlQEDNGCx2JwlrwSWSKVT4jTGIoAl9KHtxJIQNJjkpVM4LnoDMhjKYLKTyZTqbShfd3qkRZ5fn4AkEQiiQbDoRCPmlwZlsrl8siijh0ZVqrUPLiyGBbMh7rg4JN0HE5QByTkQUPIAA+yFDcTWfQgL1GUdjoZgPLgxHihC1IFDHJ4fAAIpMAErJnIMPj6sUHSVHeQyrABoOwtbtuj+wPBrBOfW7XTAMAIAAWWk7wYHE2+lAQ1jjEdDNFnc48hv+VhwADpDjJm6dVABuNffBc4OMJp5V14rs-rtJ-AKPDYpxR7xsHk5nU+PpmLhmWY5ooeaCgWq7-t8m4BGqvKauBn5Soev4Pp6OKnuy3q+gAkpW5z6j0oi0Iy3wANrlBA+ASn6thtn2AC61wqpYAgMrG9yvs8WxjLGcEavy+Y6jiWE+sQyA4V+0pHq2voaJodzIBAAAekAgD0fDKrc242OJHG2FxmyvDG3LqnyigCnSOp2NoCrdk4qRmmiZRuli7yxmUPQQDAoAQD0nDYPgIASDAZQIGIQrIH0WLoIo6yxAYeFxA4+qZlAWjBmAyCUdRoA2juRFrDO67ADAWgAPKTAAVhA4U7oQOhgIoYkQDuY7YOVWIosQMj4DuC7oOgCUFcRAA02VUYig5zggQoMMgU5wHKYIjWsFFUUitHEPRcQMX+UGzZKWX7tJZxymWlZDAmWBIU2P6qDtmg5ZtPbtv2m2Sch92ycQ+3-qVWgnShqjFVBHhwLocAjhKX0tlkvZwA4f2Phw66o1QDRAA)